# Merge a two way relation in the same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Current Data**

```
ID      | Name1      | Name2
<guid1> | XMind      | MindNode    
<guid2> | MindNode   | XMind         
<guid3> | avast      | Hitman Pro    
<guid4> | Hitman Pro | avast
<guid5> | PPLive     | Hola!    
<guid6> | ZenMate    | Hola!    
<guid7> | Hola!      | PPLive
<guid8> | Hola!      | ZenMate
```

**Required Output**

```
ID1       | ID2       | Name1  | Name2
<guid1>   | <guid2>   | XMind  | MindNode 
<guid3>   | <guid4>   | avast  | Hitman Pro  
<guid5>   | <guid7>   | PPLive | Hola!
<guid6>   | <guid8>   | Hola!  | ZenMate
```

These are relations between apps. I want to show that Avast and Hitman has a relation but in this view i do not need to show in what "direction" they have an relation. It's a given in this view that the relation goes both ways.

**EDIT:** Seems like my example was to simple. The solution doesn't work with more data.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID INT, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 1, 'XMind', 'MindNode' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 2, 'MindNode', 'XMind' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 3, 'avast', 'Hitman Pro' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 4, 'Hitman Pro', 'avast' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 5, 'PPLive Video Accelerator', 'Hola! Better Internet' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 6, 'ZenMate', 'Hola! Better Internet' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 7, 'Hola! Better Internet', 'PPLive Video Accelerator' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 8, 'Hola! Better Internet', 'ZenMate' )

SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2
FROM    @a a1
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2
        AND a1.ID < a2.ID -- avoid duplicates
```

This works however so i guess it's the Guid that is messing with me.

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I haven't looked at this for a while and i thought it worked but i just realized it does not. I've struggled all morning with this but i must admit that SQL is not really my strong suite. The thing is this.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID int, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 1, 'XMind', 'MindNode' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 2, 'MindNode', 'XMind' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 3, 'avast', 'Hitman Pro' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 4, 'PPLive Video Accelerator', 'Hola! Better Internet' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 5, 'ZenMate', 'Hola! Better Internet' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 6, 'Hitman Pro', 'avast' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 7, 'Hola! Better Internet', 'PPLive Video Accelerator' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 8, 'Hola! Better Internet', 'ZenMate' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 9, 'XX', 'A' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 10, 'XX', 'BB' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 11, 'BB', 'XX' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 12, 'A', 'XX' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 13, 'XX', 'CC' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 14, 'CC', 'XX' )

;With CTE as
(
SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2,
        CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end) ck, -- just for display
        Row_Number() over (Partition by CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end)
                           order by CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end)) as rn

FROM    @a a1
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2
)
Select ID1, ID2,Name1, Name2
from CTE C1
where rn=1
```

When i use this code it sure works fine with the names but it doesn't match the ID's correctly.

The result is

```
ID1       | ID2       | Name1  | Name2
12        | 9         | A      | X (Correct)
7         | 5         | Hola!  | ZenMate (Not Correct)   
[..]
```

I've pulled my hair all morning but i can't figure this out. I still use Guid's as ID's and just use Int's here to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: there will be only one row for MindNode   | XMind or is it possible multiple row with same result but different ID will be there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output should contain only two-way relations `('XX' + 'A') AND ('A' + 'XX')`, try this:

```
;
WITH m    (ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2) AS (
    SELECT ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2
    FROM (
        SELECT a1.ID AS ID1
              ,a2.ID AS ID2
              ,a1.Name1 AS Name1
              ,a2.Name1 AS Name2
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.Name1, a2.Name1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS n
        FROM @a AS a1
        JOIN @a AS a2
            ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2
                AND a1.Name2 = a2.Name1
    ) AS T
    WHERE n = 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID1, ID2, Name1, Name2
    FROM m
    WHERE ID1 <= ID2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID2, ID1, Name2, Name1
    FROM m
    WHERE ID1 > ID2
) AS dm
```

It produces the output as follows:

```
+------+-----+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| ID1  | ID2 | Name1                    | Name2                 |
+------+-----+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|    1 |   2 | XMind                    | MindNode              |
|    3 |   6 | avast                    | Hitman Pro            |
|    4 |   7 | PPLive Video Accelerator | Hola! Better Internet |
|    5 |   8 | ZenMate                  | Hola! Better Internet |
|    9 |  12 | XX                       | A                     |
|   10 |  11 | XX                       | BB                    |
|   13 |  14 | XX                       | CC                    |
+------+-----+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID INT, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 1, 'XMind', 'MindNode' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 2, 'MindNode', 'XMind' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 3, 'avast', 'Hitman Pro' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( 4, 'Hitman Pro', 'avast' )

SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2
FROM    @a a1
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2
        AND a1.ID < a2.ID -- avoid duplicates
```

Referring to the amendment and extension of your question, a more complicated solution is required. 
We form a [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us_en/library/ms189788.aspx) on a1.Name1,a2.Name (to get an identical we exchanged on size).
Using this we generate with [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us_en/library/ms186734.aspx) a number and use only rows from the result with number 1.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID uniqueIdentifier, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'XMind', 'MindNode' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'MindNode', 'XMind' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'avast', 'Hitman Pro' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'Hitman Pro', 'avast' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'PPLive Video Accelerator', 'Hola! Better Internet' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'ZenMate', 'Hola! Better Internet' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'Hola! Better Internet', 'PPLive Video Accelerator' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'Hola! Better Internet', 'ZenMate' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'XX', 'A' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'A', 'XX' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'XX', 'BB' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'BB', 'XX' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'XX', 'CC' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NewID(), 'CC', 'XX' )


;With CTE as
(
SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2,
        CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end) ck, -- just for display
        Row_Number() over (Partition by CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end)
                           order by CheckSum(Case when a1.Name1>a2.Name1 then a2.Name1+a1.Name1 else a1.Name1+a2.Name1 end)) as rn

FROM    @a a1
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2
)
Select *
from CTE C1
where rn=1
```

*Edit:*
If you only want to get those where both fields are fitting the needed query would simply be:

```
SELECT a1.ID AS ID1 , a2.ID AS ID2 , a1.Name1 , a2.Name1 AS Name2 
FROM @a a1 
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2 and a1.Name2 = a2.Name1 AND a1.ID < a2.ID
```

Comment: Have formatted slightly and added the relevant column aliases to match OP.

Comment: Seems like i shouldn't left out that the ID column is actually a guid. I just wanted to simplify it a bit.

Comment: Ohh! Wait! It does work even with Guids. Thanks, puh i need to work harder so i can hire smart guys like you :)

Comment: @Stuck I did an edit on my answer to to meet changed requirements.

Comment: I'm sorry @bummi but i still find some "bugs" in this. I would love to figure this out once and for all :D Let me know if you (or anyone else) have any ideas.

Comment: Hi Olaj, if you only want to get those where both fields are fitting it would be *SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2
FROM    @a a1
JOIN @a a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2 and a1.Name2 = a2.Name1        
              AND a1.ID < a2.ID*  but maybe the desired result is not clear.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work fine. Not sure why we made it so complicated last time hehe.

Comment: @Olaj maybe the desired result (input) was not clear for me, I'll make an edit on the answer.

Comment: @Olaj: Bummi's latest edit should solve your problem. Your question was a bit misleading :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER` function and use this rank in `join` instead of original `ID` column:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Name1 VARCHAR(50), Name2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'XMind', 'MindNode' )    
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'MindNode', 'XMind' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'avast', 'Hitman Pro' )  
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'Hitman Pro', 'avast' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'PPLive Video Accelerator', 'Hola! Better Internet' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'ZenMate', 'Hola! Better Internet' )       
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'Hola! Better Internet', 'PPLive Video Accelerator' )
INSERT  INTO @a VALUES  ( NEWID(), 'Hola! Better Internet', 'ZenMate' )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn FROM @a)
SELECT  a1.ID AS ID1 ,
        a2.ID AS ID2 ,
        a1.Name1 ,
        a2.Name1 AS Name2
FROM    cte a1
JOIN cte a2 ON a1.Name1 = a2.Name2 AND 
               a2.Name1 = a1.Name2 AND 
               a1.rn < a2.rn
```

Output:

```
ID1     ID2     Name1                       Name2
Guid    Guid    XMind                       MindNode
Guid    Guid    avast                       Hitman Pro
Guid    Guid    PPLive Video Accelerator    Hola! Better Internet
Guid    Guid    ZenMate                     Hola! Better Internet
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use this simple way:

```
SELECT 
    t2.ID, t3.ID ID2,
    t1.Name1,t1.Name2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN Name1 <= Name2 THEN Name1 ELSE Name2 END AS Name1,
        CASE WHEN Name1 <= Name2 THEN Name2 ELSE Name1 END AS Name2
    FROM 
        @a) t1
    JOIN
    @a t2 ON t1.Name1+t1.Name2 = t2.Name1+t2.Name2
    JOIN
    @a t3 ON t1.Name1+t1.Name2 = t3.Name2+t3.Name1
```

For this:

```
ID  | ID2 | Name1                 | Name2
----+-----+-----------------------+---------------------------
12  | 9   | A                     | XX
3   | 4   | avast                 | Hitman Pro
11  | 10  | BB                    | XX
14  | 13  | CC                    | XX
7   | 5   | Hola! Better Internet | PPLive Video Accelerator
8   | 6   | Hola! Better Internet | ZenMate
2   | 1   | MindNode              | XMind
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using a `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT a2.ID ID_1,a1.ID ID_2, a2.Name1 , a2.Name2
FROM @a a1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT ID, Name2, Name1 
    FROM @a aa
    WHERE aa.Name1 = a1.Name2 AND a1.Name1 = aa.Name2 AND a1.ID > aa.ID
) a2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try also:

```
select min(ID) ID1,
       max(ID) ID2,
       Name1,
       Name2
from ( -- Here I get all the IDs and each couple sorted 
       -- Change > to < if you don't like the order
       select ID, 
              case
                  when Name1 > Name2 then Name1
                  else Name2
              end Name1,
              case
                  when Name1 > Name2 then Name2
                  else Name1
              end Name2
       from table1
      ) as t
group by Name1, 
         Name2
```

You can even tansform this in a simgle query, without the inner one, but I think in this way it's more readable and you can understand better my approach.